# The verb ''feel'' about weather

Tags: vocabulary

Feel(V):İf you talk about how the weather feels, you describe the weather,

especially the temparature or weather or not ***you think*** it is going to

rain or snow.

I have some confusion about this explanation.

İf I say;

A) it feels wintery cold today

I think it means ; it is wintery cold today

B) İt feels rainy today

I think it means ;  I ***guess*** ,it will rain today.

Am I right?

İf so, does it mean that if I use ''feel'' with temperature (cold ,Hot) it

means the realtime situation of the weather and if I use ''feel'' with

''rainy'', ''snowy'' it means what you guess about the soon future weather.?

Comment: *It feels colder than it is.*  What does **feels** mean to you there?

Answer (score 1):

Some additions are needed to make these read correctly. In your examples. "it" is rather vague as to what "it" refers to.

> A) It feels *like* wintery cold *weather* today.
>   B) İt feels *like rain* today.

"feels like" means you have some feelings that are similar to the weather conditions described.

In A) you need *weather* because "wintery cold" is not a kind of weather.

Answer (score 1):

Yes agree, a few more additions to make this read correctly. However to give some explanation:

You say 'feel' in both cases since you are using touch senses, rather than eyesight or hearing.

It 'feels cold' as you feel cold directly through your skin, now. (Note that Cold and wintery have similar meanings in this context, so say cold, say wintery, or say cold and wintery, but not cold wintery without the 'and'!

It 'feels like rain' is a short form of the long sentence: It is not raining at the moment (otherwise you'd say it is raining!), but you feel humidity in the air which suggests it will rain (/snow) during the day.

'Its cold' and 'It feels like rain' sounds similar, but 'feels' is what you sense now, while 'feels like' is making a guess about the future.

However it is not 'feels rainy' - either: it is a rainy (adjective) day (noun), or it is raining (gerund - special type of noun), or 'it feels like rain' (future)

Sorry if this all sounds pedantic but you can only learn when someone lets you know what is right or wrong! Hope the explanation is clear enough, and helpful!

Answer (score 1):

A) It **feels like** rain today.

[the rain has not yet started. The full idea is: It feels like it is going to rain.] If feels like snow. These are used colloquially and are fine.

B) It **feels cold, hot, humid, dry, etc. today**.

Those are the two forms you can use here. **It feels** means: **The air or weather** feels cold,hot,dry, humid,etc.

C) Once you know what the weather is, **you do not need to say feel**.

The weather is rainy, hot, humid, dry, snowy.

It is very hot today. It is very cold today. It is very rainy today.